# Oracle sql check dependencies on schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle database with multiple schemas. I would like to remove some of them but there might be some dependencies between them. Is there any way to check?

Comment: what dependencies you want to check? if foreign keys are defined then you can just check the FK constraints?

Comment: I don't know if i put the right question I have 3 databases X, Y and Z. I want to see if this 3 are linked. Because I would like to delete one of them, for example Y.

Comment: A "database" is something completely different than a schema (=user) in Oracle. What exactly are you referring to? A user? Or a (pluggable) database?

Answer (score 2):

select * from DBA_DEPENDENCIES where owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME';

You can check also in code by doing this

Select * from dba_source where upper(text) like '%SCHEMA_NAME%'. -- here is stored source code of procedures, functions, package etc.

Comment: Select * from dba_source where upper(text) like '%SCHEMA_NAME%' this select it return me all the dependencied but how can I see if they are linked to another schema. For example I have owner=User and it's linked with owner=ADMUSR

Comment: I don't know if i put the right question I have 3 databases X, Y and Z. I want to see if this 3 are linked. Because I would like to delete one of them, for example Y.

Comment: Well, i think you don't know what is diffrence between 'database' and 'schema'. 
Schema == database's user
database == other database, could be oracle, teradata, mssql etc.
If you would like to search for other database use DBA_DB_LINKS(and DBA_SYNONYMS if you are using it).

Oracle sytnax for select is Select * from SCHEMA(user).TABLE_NAME@DB_LINK_FOR_EXTERNAL_DATABSE;

Comment: `dba_dependencies` is more reliable than `dba_source`, as source code could include comments or words that happen to contain the schema name. Also the text you are looking for might be in upper, lower or mixed case.

Comment: William, I agree with you, but from my experience as oracle dev, sometimes dba_source is better since you are looking for potential usage of some table/schemas - even in code. For example if you are searching in dev instance and some code is temporary disabled( is commented), dba_depenence will show nothing and source can give you something.